# Put items in List with Linq query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm getting items from an XML document that looks like this:

```
<Pages>
  <Page1>
    <item name="name1" />
    <item name="name2" />
  </Page1>
  <Page2>
    <item name="name1" />
    <item name="name2" />
  </Page2>
</Pages>
```

I want to store this in a list. So i have a `Dictionary` which should store a list of `items`.

```
private Dictionary<string, List<ItemElement>> _pages = new Dictionary<string, List<ItemElement>>();
```

Then i try to read the XML like this, but how do i add the items to the `List`? This isn't working:

```
_pages = Configuration.Elements("Pages").Elements()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName,
        x => x.Descendants("item")
            .ToList(y => 
                new ItemElement
                {
                    Name = y.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Value = "Value",
                    Origin = "Origin"
                })
            );
```

But it says: `ToList takes '0' arguments`. SO how do i solve this issue? How can i add items to the list in this linq query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the ItemElements first, then put them in a list.

```
_pages = Configuration.Elements("Pages").Elements()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName,
        x => x.Descendants("item")
            .Select(y => 
                new ItemElement
                {
                    Name = y.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Value = "Value",
                    Origin = "Origin"
                })
            )
            .ToList();
```